# Getting input from user and writing it to a text file

Tags: python

```
f=open("test.txt","w")
f.write("PERSONALINFO"+"\n")
f.write("\n")
f.close()

f=open("test.txt","a")
f.write("Customer 1 Info:""\n")
print()

print("Customer 1 input:")
user1_title=input("Enter Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms:")
user1_name=input("Enter fullname:")
user1_town=input("Enter town and country you live in:")
user1_age=input("Enter birth MM/DD/YY with numbers:""\n")

print()
print("Name:",user1_title + "",     user1_name,"\n""Hometown:",user1_town,"\n" "Age:", user1_age, file=f)


print("1.Student")
print("2.Not working")
User1_working_status=input("Enter working status:")



if user1_name=="1":
    print("student")
elif user1_name=="2":
    print("Not working")
    input("Please explain why:")
```

I can't get my `elif` statement "Explain why" to print to my text file. Can anyone help me? I've tried everything but nothing works so I'm stuck.

Comment: coz in `if` statement you need to use `User1_working_status` instead of `user1_name`?

Comment: Is the issue that you can't prompt the user for `"Please explain why: "`? Or that you can't write the output from the prompt to a text file?

Comment: No, it don't work. When I print something I can write file=f and then the printed message will be written in the text file, but with user input I can't use file=f so it will only print in the console and not in my text file

Comment: Why are you using `print` to write to the file when you already have an open file object? You also don't close the file so the writes probably aren't being flushed from the buffer.

Comment: It's not working because your condition is checking for `user1_name` not `User1_working_status`.

Comment: I've tried everything so I don't understand..I am collecting user information so I'm printing questions in the terminal and taking the information to a text file. But now my user has different job options and if they pick number 2 "Not working" they will need to explain why, and that won't print in the text file. It will only write "2" and not what they write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to create and append all the information to a text file. For the `Explain why` part, you should store the information to a variable and then write to file. If you use the `with` context manager for file I/O, you would not have to close the file explicitly.

```
user1_title=input("Enter Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms: ")
user1_name=input("Enter fullname: ")
user1_town=input("Enter town and country you live in: ")
user1_age=input("Enter birth MM/DD/YY with numbers:""\n")
print("1.Student")
print("2.Not working")
User1_working_status=input("Enter working status: ")


with open("test.txt", 'a+') as f:
    if User1_working_status=="1":
        f.write("{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n".format("Name: " + user1_title + " " + user1_name, "Town: " + user1_town, "Age: " + user1_age, "Working status: student"))        
    elif User1_working_status=="2":
        explain = input("Please explain why: ")
        f.write("{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n".format("Name: " + user1_title + " " + user1_name, "Town: " + user1_town, "Age: " + user1_age, "Working status: Not Working", "Reason: " + explain))
print("Information written to test.txt")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To write in your text file, you should use `f.write` instead of printing (which shows on the console). And as stated in the comments, remember to close the file when the program finished.

Also the working status is set in `User1_working_status` variable, and your if statement condition reads `user1_name`.